# Cpp getline in a while loop works once, then reads until the end of the file

Tags: c++, input, getline

I am writing a program that take a command redirected file as the standard input, so instead of `cin` getting input from the keyboard, I run my program with `./teamBalancer < inputFile.txt > outputFile.txt`.

The problem I'm having is that `getline` in the `while` loop reads the first line perfectly and outputs fine, but then it just reads the rest of the file in one line. I have tried everything from `stringstream`s to just `getline` and have read so many forums. Why is this happening?

Here is my code:

```
  //USER INPUT--------------------------------------------------------------
  while (cin) {
   string attackString, defenseString;
   getline(cin, attackString, ',');
   getline(cin, defenseString);

   int attack, defense;
   attack = atoi(attackString.c_str());
   defense = atoi(defenseString.c_str());
   cout<<attack<<" "<<defense<<endl;
  }
```

and the sample input is this:

```
5,1

9,1

7,4

1,3

1,3

10,4

4,5

7,4
```

and the corresponding output is...

```
5 1

9 1

0 0
```

Both of these are in txt files and the 0 0 for the last output is because the last line is empty? I don't understand why `getline` can't continue reading the file line by line like it does with the first one.

Thank you so much to anyone who helps and if you need any clarification please let me know! Thank you :)

Comment: Check using getline("\n"); after getline(cin, defenseString);

Comment: what is your loop condition testing?

Comment: If I put getline(cin, temp, '\n'); after getline(cin, defenseString); the output becomes 5 1   0 0, so the second line 9 1 disappears as well. And the loop condition was previously while (getline(cin, line)), so it was testing until getline returned false, but that didn't work, so now it tests while (cin), which, I believe is synonymous to while (cin.good). Basically, until cin has nothing to read. I may be wrong...

Comment: Run in a debugger. Set a breakpoint after the two getlines and see what you have in the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Code you presented looks good. I tested it under Windows without any changes and got the following result:

5 1
9 1
7 4
1 3
1 3
10 4
4 5
7 4
0 0

So it looks like your input file encoding is messed up.
Can you please check the line endings of your input txt. Are they all the same and are the EOL chars the default one for your system?

The 0 0 in the last row is that cin still contains something at the end (the EOF char) but it is not able to translate it to the wished numbers, to avoid this you can use this:

```
 while (!cin.eof())
```

Now you are checking if you are on the end of a file.

Sorry currently i can not write comments.

br,
zinnjonas

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you so much! To think that the hours I spent trying to fix this problem and find a way around it, it was in the input file encoding the whole time :( Of course I thought that the input file may have had something fishy with it, but I just created a regular txt. file. Apparently, new line characters are encoded differently on Mac and Windows. I just created a new file but instead of using TextEdit I used my text editor for coding. It worked, so thank you very, very much!!!